# Capacitors in Combination

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

In the solution, how is C1 and C2 on either left or right connected in series? It seems like the two C1s on top are connected in series, but I'm not sure though. 
[image]

Comment: Read carefully: $C_s$ is correctly a series with $C_1$ and $C_2$, then $C_{p1}$ is a parallel between $C_3$ and the two $C_s$ right and left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good rule of thumb

> If the same current goes through elements $A$ and $B$, then $A$ and $B$ are in series

Clearly the current going $C_1$ on the left is *not* the same as the one going through $C_1$ on the right. They are not in series!

Similarly, on the left the current going through $C_1$ is the same going through $C_2$: They are in series

Comment: Very helpful answer, my physics instructor said that the indication that the capacitors are in series if their terminals are connected alternately,in the picture it seems like both left terminals are connected